# Android: How to get Google Charts to show up in Android Chrome Browser Webview

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-chrome, webview

I created a web-based login interface and some charts using AngularJS and the Google Charts API. The interface works completely fine on my laptop using Chrome. However, when I try to view the page on a webview in an Android App I created, the AngularJS does not work and neither do the charts. I enabled javascript in the Webview using "webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);" and still this issue persists.

Moreover, when I view the page on my Android phone's Chrome browser, the AngularJS login features work, but I get a "**plugin not supported**" error for the Google charts without any further clarification. So my questions are the following:

1. How can I display Google Charts on my Android phone's Chrome Browser? Is there some plugin or tool I can install to get Google charts to show up on the Android Browser?
2. How do I get the Android app webview to use Chrome rather than the default browser? So once I get it working for Chrome, I can display the page on my app.

Comment: I am not sure this is the exact solution you are looking for but read this https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2710225?hl=en and https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#notshowing i think you have to install a flash plugin manually and try.

Comment: Documentation on Google Charts states it is using HTML5/SVG https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index. You are going to have to debug your javascript to figure out what is going on and who is generating the "plugin not supported" error.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, the type of chart I was using (Annotated Timeline) uses Flash which is not default installed on Android nor is it in the Play Store. So the solution was to use an Annotation Chart Instead (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart).